# Can you specify the order of wrapped elements in CSS flex?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I have a `<div>` that uses CSS flex to keep it responsive.

I am looking for a way to specify the order that elements are wrapped in.

For example, I need

`1 - 2 - 3`

To become

```
1
3
2
```

When fully wrapped.

Current code: https://jsfiddle.net/g0L44e5b/

Is this possible?

Comment: Post your code please. We need to see the current layout, and when/how things wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this pen out:

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/YPzyYa

What the pen does --
First gives each element a default class with an order attribute:

```
.icon {
  order: 0 !important;
 }
.username {
  order: 1 !important;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px;
}
.search {
  order: 2 !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then it gives a class to each each flexbox a specific ordering attribute:

```
.bar-2 {
  .username {
    order: 2;
  }
}
.icon-3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

Apply the sorting classes to your case and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can , use [order](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property) property:

```css
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  }
p:last-child{
  order:1;
  }
p:nth-child(2) {
  order:2;
    }
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

here is an handy ressource https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

---

**edit after your edit**

wrap and mediaquerie can be used :

```css
body {
  display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;
  }
p {
  flex:1;
  min-width:380px;
  margin:10px;
  border:solid;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 800px) {
p:last-child{
  order:1;
  }
p:nth-child(2) {
  order:2;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use media queries, you can use `flex-direction: column` on the parent element and `order: 1;` , `order: 2;` etc. on the child elements to put them in any order you need.